# Url representation in php

Tags: php, url

I am used to representing embedded url information like this:

```
http://test.com/reports/statement.php?company=ABC&q=1
```

how would I do it like this instead?

```
http://test.com/reports/ABC/Q1
```

Comment: Search for URL Rewrite, there're plenty of articles in the web.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Apache mod_rewrite` to achieve this.

If your server has it enabled, you could do something like this in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /statement.php?company=$1&q=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] to access anything in the URL docpath *after* the address of your script.

e.g.

http://test.com/reports/statement.php/ABC/Q1

...then in statement.php you would have the string "/ABC/Q1" in $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']

Of course, you'll need to setup your webserver to match the URL and target the correct script based on the HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, you have to use url rewriting.

Usually a php application that make use of it, it applies the pattern called **Front Controller**.

This means that almost every url is rewritten to point to a single file, where the $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] is used to decide what to do, usually by matching with patterns you define for your actions, or return a 404 error if the url doesn't match any of the specified patterns.

This is called **routing** and every modern php framework has a component that helps doing this work.

A smart move would also be providing a tool to generate urls for your resources instead of handwriting them, so that if you change an url pattern you do not have to rewrite it everywhere.

If you need a complex routing system, check out the routing component of some major frameworks out there, e.g. Symfony2, Zend Framework 2, Auraphp.

For the simplest php router out there, check instead [GluePHP](http://gluephp.com/). The codebase is tiny so you can make yourself an idea on how the stuff works, and even implement a small router that fits your needs if you want to.